# Silverlight 5 INotify OnPropertyChanged not triggered?

Tags: silverlight, binding

If I bind a TextBox to an object's (Merchandise is the object) property like:

Text="{Binding Path=Merchandise.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}

```
<TextBox x:Name="QuantityTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="70" Text="{Binding Path=Merchandise.Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue='0', FallbackValue='0', ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

The DataContext is set to my ViewModel which contains (among other properties) the declared property of type Merchandise.

```
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)

    If PropertyChangedEvent IsNot Nothing Then

        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)

        Select Case e.PropertyName


            Case "Merchandise"

                DoSomething()

            Case Else

        End Select

    End If

End Sub


 Private _Merchandise As DC.SL.Services.WebServiceMerchandise.Merchandise
Public Property Merchandise() As DC.SL.Services.WebServiceMerchandise.Merchandise
    Get
        Return _Merchandise
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DC.SL.Services.WebServiceMerchandise.Merchandise)
        _Merchandise = value
        OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Merchandise"))
    End Set
End Property
```

When I input changes in the TextBox the PropertyChanged event is NOT triggered.  The only way I can work around this is by creating duplicate properties in my ViewModel ... i.e. Quantity and then later when Ok button is clicked I assigned the ViewModel properties to my Merchandise object.  But this is definitely not efficient seems to defeat the purpose of being able to Bind using Path=SomeObject.Property.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Please show the Merchandise property in the ViewModel and use code-formatting :)

Comment: Updated original post with code blocks.  I'm was hoping there is a simple way to work with Binding Path=Object.Property with PropertyChanged notifications.  The correct input text is being stored in Merchandise.Quantity, but the PropertyChanged event is NOT being fired.

Comment: Hugh... And you're sure you have the correct datacontext? And if you make a breakpoint in the setter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise a `PropertyChanged` event on the properties of your `Merchandise` class. So that class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as well as your view model class. Otherwise, the UI doesn't know that anything's changed.